# Can I change a user password in Linux from the command line with no interactivity?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, freebsd, password

I have a specific use case where I would really like to be able to change a user's password with a single command with no interactivity. This is being done in a safe fashion (over SSH, and on a system with only one user able to be logged in), so it's fine to expose the new password (and even the old one, if necessary) on the command line. FWIW, it's a Ubuntu system.

I just want to avoid having to add something Expect-like to this system for just this one task.

Comment: For those who want to do this on FreeBSD: `echo "newpassword" | pw usermod theusername -h 0`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use [chpasswd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/chpasswd.8.html).

```
echo user:pass | /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `usermod` with the `-p` option to provide a password hash (not the actual password).  You can generate the password hash using something like `mkpasswd -m sha-256` or `mkpasswd -m md5`

Comment: ...But my AIX system doesn't have `usermod` :'( -- I'll fix the tags on the question.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

1. Hash the password on your local system.
2. Connect to the remote machine (where you want to change the password)
3. Feed the hashed password & the username to a creative `sed` script that updates your system's password file (`/etc/shadow`, `/etc/master.passwd`, whatever it happens to be).

Answer (score 1):

The `passwd` utility has a --stdin option that states:

> This option is used to indicate that passwd should read the new password from standard input, which can be a pipe.

Syntax:

```
echo "newpass" | passwd --stdin user1
```

Even though you mentioned you don't care, you could put the password in a text file and then do `cat pass.txt` instead of the echo command, that way it doesn't show up in the bash history.

Comment: That's the one.  `echo VerySecret | passwd --stdin username`

Comment: My Ubuntu system doesn't have `--stdin` as an option for `passwd`.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. I checked on both a CentOS system and on a Mac and they have the --stdin option, so the removal of it must be a Ubuntu thing.

Comment: @RyanM. FreeBSD (and AFAIK NetBSD and OpenBSD, AIX, HP-UX and Solaris last I checke) don't support `--stdin` either - mainly because it's a big giant security hole waiting to happen :-)

Comment: @quanta: Or start the `echo "newpass" | passwd --stdin user1` line with a space; that way it won't go to bash history at all.

Answer (score 1):

If `--stdin` option is not working we can basically use two options:

1. Either use another utilty called `chpaswd` in your script.
2. OR use `echo "current_password\nnew_password\nnew_password" | passwd user_name`